# TEXT CSV cant create csv file from csv print

Tags: perl, export-to-csv

I am trying to write the csv->print out put to a file, the filename I want to use is in $_ and the data prints out from the csv->print command correct on screen. I just can't work out how to get it in a file.

```
$_ = $ARGV[0];
s/^[^=]*=//;

while (@ARGV) {
my $file = shift;
open my $IN, '<', $file or die $!;
my $html = do { local $/; <$IN> };
$te->parse($html);
}
for my $table ($te->tables) {

#print $_."\n";
open (NEWCSV, '>> '.$_);
    print NEWCSV $csv->print(*STDOUT{IO}, $_) for $table->rows;
close (NEWCSV);
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open a file for output, and use its filehandle instead of `*STDOUT{IO}`:

```
open my $FH, '>', 'file.csv';
$csv->print($FH, $_) for $table->rows;
```